# well-defined function verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $G_m$ denote the set of invertible congruence classes in $Z_m$ . Define a map $F: G_{mn} → G_{m} × G_{n}$ by the rule $F([a]_{mn}) = ([a]_m , [a]_n)$.

if ($m,$n) = 1 prove that $F$ is a well-defined function.

I know from the definition of well-defined that the function's output is the same whatever the representative we use, but I'm stuck proving it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to show that the map $[a]_{mn}\mapsto[a]_m$ is well-defined, since if this is well defined, then clearly $[a]_{mn}\mapsto[a]_n$ is well-defined, and hence the product, $[a]_{mn}\mapsto([a]_m, [a]_n)$, is also well-defined.

First let's see an example where it fails. Take $m=3$ and $n=3$, so that $mn=9$. Consider $[2]_{9}$. Then we cannot choose whether $[2]_m=1$ and $[2]_n=2$ or whether $[2]_m=2$ and $[2]_n=1$.

Now suppose $(m,n)=1$. For any $a$ such that $[a]_{mn}\in G_{mn}$,
$$
a = cmn + s
$$
for $s=0,1,\dots,mn-1$. Furthermore, because $(m,n)=1$, we can find a $b = 0,1,\dots,n-1$ and an $r=0,1,\dots,m-1$ such that
$$
s = bm + r
$$
Then it is clear that $[a]_m=[r]_m$, so it is well-defined. We need only show now that $[r]_m\in G_m$. However, this is clear, since $[a]_{mn}\in G_{mn}\implies (s, mn)=1\implies(s,m)=(r,m)=1\implies[r]_m\in G_m$.